# Function not showing up on unity button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity and C#. I am trying to use a button to trigger something, but the function is not showing up. Here is the code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExitButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnButtonTrigger () {
        Debug.Log("Application Quitting");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of where the problem is:

[image: Image showing the probleme]

Comment: Try putting the ExitButton script on the button as a component and then drag that component into the OnClick() where you currently have the ExitButton. Your function should then appear in the dropdown menu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

attach that script to a game object as a component then drag that object to **OnClick** and you will find the functions.